# Creating a Simpler Home URL for ASP.Net Web Applications

Tags: asp.net, routes, seo

Hopefully a simple question:

When creating a typical asp.net webforms app, the "real" home page url will be something like "https://example.com/myapp/index.aspx".

Of course, this looks like garbage in the user's web browser. Is there a simple way to have it appear as just "https://example.com"?

Is the solution a routing rule of some sort?

Thanks for any help,
-Pete

Answer (score 0):

Well, you only see/have/get a sub folder, since that is where you sent/published the web site to.

So, if you publish to the root of the web site, then in theory, yes, you should be able to just type in the "base" URL of the site. In some cases, due to a "default" page setting, then when you type in:

```
www.zoo.com
```

It "might" say default to:

```
www.zoom.com/Default.aspx
```

now, of course we "often" setup what are called friendly URL's, and thus this will keep (hide) the aspx extension.

But, there should not be the sub folder you have, and that suggests/means that you published to a sub folder of your web site.

Comment: Yes, the site is at a subfolder (typical for asp.net apps) -- is this a solvable problem with such sites?

Comment: Having a sub site or sub folder? Yes, typical. Having a sub-site page become the root of the site - no, not so typical (and if it was, then why you having trouble finding a solution then, right??). You could put re-direct code in the base site default.aspx page then I suppose. (I don't have ready solution - hopefully someone else will chime in).

Comment: Yes, currently, going to "example.com" redirects to the "https://example.com/myapp/index.aspx" page -- it's just that the visible url in browsers looks awful

Comment: You could use a Server.Transfer("~/Zoo/Fun/MyWebPageUpload.aspx", False).  If you look at server.transfer, it does NOT update the URL. this of course would only make sense for the first landing page, but server.transfer() jumps to any page, but the URL display in the browser does not update. Of course additional event code will likely result in the URL updating.  But then again, are we trying to have a SPA effect here.